# Write to csv file

Tags: csv, ansible

I need some contents to be written in csv format to a file using ansible

```
shell: ps -ef | grep java | awk '{print $1}'
register: username

shell: ps -ef | grep java | awk '{print $2}'
register: id
```

The output for username will be similar to :

```
root
admin
test_admin
```

The output for id will be similar to:

```
1232
4343
2233
```

so I want this to be written to a csv file as

```
root,1232
admin,4343
test_admin,2233
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of the zip, map and join filters to achieve your desired result:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: combination of two lists
      set_fact:
        lines: "{{ [1,2,3]|zip(['a','b','c'])|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lines }}"
    - name: transform each line into a string
      set_fact:
        lines: "{{ lines | map('join', ', ') | list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lines }}"
    - name: combine lines
      set_fact:
        lines: "{{ lines | join('\n') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lines }}"
    - name: write lines to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ lines }}"
        dest: "output.csv"
```

Or when you combine the filters together:

```
- name: write lines to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ [1,2,3] | zip(['a','b','c']) | map('join', ', ')  | join('\n') }}"
    dest: "output.csv"
```

The content of output.csv will be:

```
1, a
2, b
3, c
```

Comment: I can point you to the documentation for filters: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id12. If you run the first playbook, it prints out what I do in each step. Is one of the steps unclear?

Comment: Thank you, this worked for two list.```lines: "{{tmp.stdout_lines| zip (tech.stdout_lines) |list }}"``` Didnt work for three list ```lines: "{{tmp.stdout_lines| zip (tech.stdout_lines)| zip (app.stdout_lines)|list }}"``` Can you please tell me what needs to be changed?

Comment: It should be {{tmp.stdout_lines| zip (tech.stdout_lines, app.stdout_lines)|list }}